# This version of Xcode cannot be used with OS X Server

Tags: xcode, server, xcode8, osx-server

I just download OSX Server (5.1.7) and I have this message which made me crazy! 
I already tried to:

- reboot
- re-install (fully) xcode and server
- accept Licence after re-install
- execute : sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode (same on Server).
- reboot, reboot and re-reboot

still nothing works.

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  Latest (App Store) versions of both Server and Xcode are installed on my CI server, but it doesn't work.  I've even checked the build numbers of Server and Xcode against the builds Apple currently lists (Xcode: 8A218a, and Server: 15S7055, see https://developer.apple.com/download/) as recommended installs.  Everything appears correct on my end, but Server insists Xcode 8 is not compatible with the current version of Server (5.1.7).

Comment: I find a 'solution' today : i go to OSX Server 5.2 Beta...

Comment: Yup.  Looks like the 5.2 works just fine.  I didn't see it on the beta section of the download page.  Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: also happening with Xcode 8.3.3 as of 6 June 2017

App Store has no updates available for Server.

Comment: Ditto @MaxMacLeod

Answer (score 0):

Having experienced this on updating to Xcode 8.3.3 as of June 6 2017, the solution was to select "choose Xcode and reset", then reboot.

This approach did not seem to affect the configuration or Bots.

After rebooting, open Server and follow the dialogue to login as "Xcode Server".

Switching users back to the Server admin, everything should now be green. Viewing the Server in Xcode's Report Navigator, all Bots should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering if it was a permissions issue or something similar.  My fix was to go into Disk Utility and run first aid on my drive.  Rebooted and everything seems to have fired right back up.  No need to reset Xcode/Server or anything crazy like that.

Hopefully this works for others.